# json2html not working in JSP

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying out with json2html and I have this issue. What the code does is iterating through a json object and creating

My code works fine with html but fails with jsp . The problem is that thes value from the json are not picked in the jsp. I have given the jsp and html code below and the values are put in an alert box

Any help is appreciated

## HTML - (WORKS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.json2html.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = {"tag":"td","html":"${fraudFees}"};
    var data = [
    {"fraudFees":3.0}
    ];
    var str = json2html.transform(data,template);
    alert("str is"+str);
     // output is str is <td>3</td>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

## (JSP - DOES NOT WORK)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.json2html.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var template = {"tag":"td","html":"${fraudFees}"};
    var data = [
    {"fraudFees":3.0}
    ];
    var str = json2html.transform(data,template);
    alert("str is"+str);
     // output is str is <td></td>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: check source path for your scripts. may be in case of jsp you should use some base path

Comment: @Uooo - No errorts on the console  The scripts are loaded fine and they are getting picked up .                            One thing that happens is that when we view the generated html , the values for ${fraudFees}" is replaced with empty quotes like
var template = {"tag":"td","html":""};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var template = {"tag":"td","html":"${fraudFees}"};
```

`${fraudFees}` is an [EL Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). That means, your JSP checks if the variable or object `fraudFees` exist and tries to render it as a string. Since there is no such object, it renders an empty string.

HTML does not know about Expression Language, therefore you see `${fraudFees}` in the HTML version of your page.

Possible solutions:

- Escape the `$` using `\$` (I would not do that since it makes the Javascript code harder to read)
- Place the Javascript in an external file
- Use a [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) in your inline Javascript

Comment: Thanks .. That was the reason